# New iOS6 Maps: can they be stored? Can I provide offline maps on my app?

Tags: sdk, mkmapview, ios6, ios6-maps

I am currently developing an iPhone App which needs the maps to be stored. 
I was planning to use OpenStreetMaps but I would like to know if Apple would allow the new map tiles to be stored in order to show them offline.
I can't find anything about it in the iOS Dev Center.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, do you have any update on this matter? Did you go with OSM, or did you get an answer to this question somewhere else?